# How to swap two characters (L and R) with each other in a String java

Tags: java

Here are the basics you need to know:

```
L - Left
R - Right
S - Straight
U - U-Turn
```

So the string is basically a series of movements, and your output must be the retracement of them (will take you back on the same path you came from and reaches the same destination).

I've figured out all the patterns (reverse string, U goes to S, L goes to R, R goes to L, remove first S). I just need to know how I can replace the L's and R's with each other.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.*;

public class DogWalk {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File("input.dat"));
            String line;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("***  Can't open input.dat ***");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        int i = 0;
        while(input.hasNextInt()) {
            i += input.nextInt();

        }
        
        ArrayList<String> n = new ArrayList<String>();
        int count = -1;
        
        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            n.add(input.nextLine());
            count++;
        }
        
        // Loop to parse through string and make changes
        for (int j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
            String nstr = "";
            String t = n.get(j); // Getting each string
            t = t.substring(1); // Removing first S
            char ch;
            
            if(t.charAt(t.length() - 1) == 'U') { // Replacing U with S
                t = t.replace("U", "S");
            }
            
            for (int b=0; b<t.length(); b++) { // Loop to make string backwards
                ch= t.charAt(b);
                nstr= ch+nstr; 
            }
            
            t = nstr;
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
}
```

So that's the main code, the replacing L and R should occur in the big loop at the bottom. My attempted solution to this was to just go through it with a loop, but it just runs into the problem of replacing itself and then either going full L's or full R's. Here's my input.dat file by the way (this was part of school requirements would've rather did it without the data file).
Input:

```
3
SRLLRLU
SSLRRRLSLRLU
SSSSSRSLLSRU
```

Feel like I'm just missing an easy solution. Just need some help.
Here's the sample output:

```
SRLRRL
SRLRSRLLLRS
SLSRRSLSSSS
```

Comment: Can you please provide a valid output for the input.dat file given above?

Comment: If you go straight to go to work, would you get home by only doing U-turns?

Comment: You would get home by doing a U-Turn (which is guaranteed, the input always has one), then going straight back

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a problem with using `t.replace("U", "S")`. This is not suitable for multiple replacements. It's much better to use `StringBuilder` (because `String` is immutable) and one time go through the original `String` and build a new one with all required replacements letter by letter.

```java
public class DogWalk {

    public static void main(String... args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.dat"))) {
            int total = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
                System.out.println(convert(scan.nextLine()));
        }
    }

    private static String convert(String str) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length() - 1);

        for (int i = str.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);

            if (ch == 'U')
                buf.append('S');
            else if (ch == 'L')
                buf.append('R');
            else if (ch == 'R')
                buf.append('L');
            else
                buf.append(ch);
        }

        return buf.toString();
    }

}
```